# Ubuntu roll back to previous kernel: linux-image-3.11.0-11

Tags: apt, kernel

I had too many kernel updates and the only ones that worked for me were "pushed away".

Any suggestions on how can I reinstall kernel version "linux-image-3.11.0-11"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install any kernel version that is in [the repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/kernel/linux-image).

For example, for the 3.11.0-11 (for Ubuntu 13.10) kernel, invoke as a terminal command:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.11.0-11-generic
```

Answer (score 2):

All kernels are kept unless you [explicitly uninstall them](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu).

To choose which kernel you want to use, at boot, hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> to see the Grub menu, scroll down with the arrow keys to "Advanced options for Ubuntu", and you will see a menu where you can select a kernel. You want one of the ones that *doesn't* say "(Recovery mode)".

Comment: I know that. That's what I've been using for the last 3 times, but now however, the oldest kernel disappeared.
My choices are 15,14,13,12 - no 11..